# Print out test names found by junit console launcher

Tags: java, console, junit5

We are using Junit console launcher (junit-platform-console-standalone-1.4.0) to run our Junit 5 tests from terminal.

We just wonder if:

- Can one print out the test names found by the console launcher in the classpath when using the --include-tag option (only printing test names out, no test started)?
- Can one alter the order to tests to be started when using the --include-tag option?